# PBE AlgorithmParameters not available

Tags: java, security, google-api-java-client, java-security

I have a problem i try to authenticate with google api using ouath2 with generated .p12 key.

The issuse is that when the google credential api tries to set .p12 key it throws 
java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: PBE AlgorithmParameters not available.

My machine run Windows 10 Home 64bit creators update and i have jdk 1.6 installed. 
I tried launching project from netbeans and intellij idea the issuse is the same on both. My co-workers launch project from linux and everything works. I also tried to set jce policies to unlimited.

Here is a stack trace dump

```
   Error during init Google Play API
java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: PBE AlgorithmParameters not available
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.parseAlgParameters(PKCS12KeyStore.java:527)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1267)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
    at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:110)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(GoogleCredential.java:670)
    at com.iapps.pdf_platform.payment.AndroidPublisherHelper.authorizeWithServiceAccount(AndroidPublisherHelper.java:70)
    at com.iapps.pdf_platform.payment.AndroidPublisherHelper.init(AndroidPublisherHelper.java:91)
    at com.iapps.pdf_platform.payment.GooglePlayPaymentVerification.checkGooglePurchase(GooglePlayPaymentVerification.java:110)
    at com.iapps.pdf_platform.payment.GooglePlayPaymentVerification.veriifyForService(GooglePlayPaymentVerification.java:96)
    at com.iapps.pdf_platform.service.GooglePlayPaymentVerificationService.verifyPurchase(GooglePlayPaymentVerificationService.java:102)
    at com.iapps.pdf_platform.service.GooglePlayPaymentVerificationService.verfifyGooglePlayPayments(GooglePlayPaymentVerificationService.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1056)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1128)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5292)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:615)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:567)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5264)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5252)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy311.verfifyGooglePlayPayments(Unknown Source)
    at com.iapps.pdf_platform.service.__EJB31_Generated__GooglePlayPaymentVerificationService__Intf____Bean__.verfifyGooglePlayPayments(Unknown Source)
    at com.iapps.pdf_platform.servlet.Tests.doGet(Tests.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBE AlgorithmParameters not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:142)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:659)
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(AlgorithmParameters.java:113)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.parseAlgParameters(PKCS12KeyStore.java:523)
    ... 62 more
```

The .p12 key is using BC provider

```
    Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: BC

Your keystore contains 1 entry

privatekey, 2017-07-10, PrivateKeyEntry,
```

Comment: May Java 1.6 be the issue? Are your colleagues using the same version?

Comment: No I think it's bouncy castle provider issue because the provider is configured in jdk but is not loaded in application.

Comment: Jdk6 is very old version. Latest version of Jdk has many issues fixed. You should upgrade and try once.

Answer (score 1):

I added Bouncy Castle Provider to java.secuirty file and bouncy castle jars to jdk. And everything works as expected. The jvm simply didn't have the provider for algorithm used to decrypt key.